# Exponential Equation Calculus

Tags: calculus

$$
\ a^{n} = n, where  \ a ∈ (0,∞)\
$$
 Let $ \ R_a\ $ represent the number of distinct real solutions to the equation for a value of $\ a\ $.

What is the largest value of $\ a\ $ for which $\ R_a = 1 ?\ $ What is the solution $\ a?\ $

Find $\ R_a\ $ for all $\ a ∈ (0,∞)\ $ Do not need solution, only $\ R_a.\ $

Answer:
   $$ \ f(n) \Longrightarrow n*\ln(a) = \ln(n) \ $$
   $$ \ f'(n) \Longrightarrow \ln(a) = \frac{1}{n} \ $$
Then rearrange:
  $$ \ f(n) \Longrightarrow  n*\ln(a) - \ln(n) = 0 \ $$
   $$ \ f'(n) \Longrightarrow  ln(a) - \frac{1}{n} = 0 \ $$
Comment:
I substitute some values into the derivative to find a critical value.  $\ a=e^1\ $ and $\ n=1\ $ substituted into the derivative results in zero.  Appreciate your suggestions.  I am not too sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: What exactly is your question? and what does $a^n = n, \in$ (s.t) mean?

Comment: I think this can be of some help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Did someone else write that formula? I think it would be better if written with more words and fewer symbols, especially when the symbols are used in non-standard ways.

Comment: @David K I updated.  Thank you.

Comment: @raffa11111 Lambert W function in form of xe^x=y but this function in form of b^x=x.  Best I can do is ln(a)=ln(n)e^(ln(n^-1).  Then x=ln(n) but the exponent is ln(1/n).  Can you elaborate on your answer?  Thanks.

Comment: f(n) implies n.ln a = ln a is meaningless because a function cannot imply a statement and f is undefined.   In otherwords, it's a poof proof.

Comment: I don’t think it’s hard. Draw some pictures.

Answer (score 1):

All steps for solving the equation 
$$a^x=x$$
$$e^{x\ln(a)}=x$$
$$e^{-x\ln(a)}=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$xe^{-x\ln(a)}=1$$
$$-xe^{-x\ln(a)}=-1$$
$$-x\ln(a)e^{-x\ln(a)}=-\ln(a)$$
Let $X=-x\ln(a)$
$$Xe^X=-\ln(a)$$
From the definition of the Lambert W function (in real domain) :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function
$$X=W\left(-\ln(a)\right)$$
$$-x\ln(a)=W\left(-\ln(a)\right)$$
The solution is :
$$x=-\frac{W\left(-\ln(a)\right)}{\ln(a)}$$

In the real domain, $W(X)$ is single valuated for $X\geq 0$ and is multi valuated : $W_0(X)$ and $W_{-1}(X)$ for $e^{-1}<X<0$.

If $\quad a>e^{1/e}\quad$ then $\quad -\ln(a)<-\frac{1}{e} \quad $ there is no real root.

If $\quad a=e^{1/e}\quad$ then $\quad -\ln(a)=-\frac{1}{e} \quad $ a root is $\quad x=e$.

If $\quad 1<a<e^{1/e}\quad$ then $\quad -\frac{1}{e}<-\ln(a)<0 \quad $ they are two real roots : One on the branch $W_0$ and one on the branch $W_{-1}$ .

If $\quad a=1\quad$ then $\quad -\ln(a)=0 \quad $ a root is $\quad x=1$ .

If $\quad 0<a<1 \quad$ then $\quad -\ln(a)>0 \quad $ there is one real root $x=-\frac{W_0\left(-\ln(a)\right)}{\ln(a)}$ .

This allows to answer to your questions I) and II).

Comment: I saw a derivation of the Lambert W function using Newton’s Method.  We have not learned the Lambert W function and am not too sure we can use this.  On the other hand, on a graph a=1 which is 1^x=x has one intersection at (1,0).  No solution for a>1.5.  2 solutions for 1 < a <= 1.5.  In addition there are solutions for a<1, like a=0.5.

Comment: The border between one and two solutions is not $a=1.5$ but is $a=e^{1/e}\simeq 1.445...$  For $a=0.5$ the solution is $x=-\frac{W_0\left(-\ln(0.5)\right)}{\ln(0.5)}\simeq  0.641186...$

Comment: Without the Lambert W function, you can draw $a$ as a function of $x$ $$a=x^{1/x}$$. Study this function : From $a=0$ to $1$ show that $x$ increases up to $e^{1/e}$. Then for $a>1$ show that $x$ decreases to $x=1$ when $a\to\infty$. With this you can answer.

Comment: I have found the value e^1/e and understand the explanation until the end with five If's.  For instance, a>e^1/e transform with -ln to -ln(a) < -1/e.  But how does one know there is no real root.  Do I look at the graph of W(x) or did you input this into the formula for x?

Comment: What is the maximum value of $x^x$ ? Do you think that a value of $x$ exists such as $a$ could be higher than this maximum value ?

Comment: From the graph, a = x^1/x, at the max x = e.  I want  to connect this back to graph of Lambert W and ur explain, -ln (a) = -1/e?

Comment: Forget the Lambert W function. Now it appears that the exercise is addressed  to students which are not familiar with special functions. The maximum of $a=x^{1/x}$ is reached for $x=e$ and $a_{max}=e^{1/e}$. So, there exist no $x$ so that $a>e^{1/e}$.

Comment: if, from you,$ \ -ln(a) = \frac{-1}{e} \ $ then sub into the ratio, $ \ \frac{W( \frac{-1}{e} )} { \frac{-1}{e} } \ $ =  $ \ \frac{-1} {\frac{-1}{e} } \ $ = e = x

Comment: But $ \ -ln(a) = 0 \ $, sub into ratio, $ \ \frac{W(0)} { 0 } \ $ =  $ \ \frac{0} {0} \ $ ?

Comment: When $a\to 1$ then $\epsilon=-\ln(a)\to 0$ and : $$\text{Limit}_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{W(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}=1$$ Thus $x(a=1)=1$.

Comment: As a matter of fact, when one uses a special function in calculus, one have to know the properties of the special function. In the present case, one have to know the series expansion of $W(x)$ for $x$ close to $0$ : $$W(x)=x+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{(-k)^{k-1}x^k}{k!}$$ See Eq.(13) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

Comment: There is some algorithm to compute which I did not study  So I tried to compute with wolfram alpha with input $ \ \frac{-1}{e} \ $ but did not enter correctly

Comment: WolfralAlpha give the correct result $W(-1/e)=-1$. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LambertW(-1%2Fe)

Comment: -ln (a) = 0 so put in W (0) = 0?

Comment: I already answer about $W(0)=0$. See the above infinite series. And obwiously $0e^0=0$. Also WolframAlpha gives the result : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LambertW(0) . We are wasting time. You need to learn more background in books, not in forums. This is the end of the discussion. Goodbye.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.